# How to write objects in subcollection in Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write an object in the Firestore subcollection. Such as

```
category > categoryValue > documentid > documentObject
```

What I could achieve is,

```
category > categoryValue > anotherDocumentName > documentid > documentObject
```

I wrote the code using Java (I think language is not an issue here),

```
db.collection("category").document("categoryName").collection("documentName").add(document);
```

I could not find a way to write something like

```
db.collection("category").document("categoryName").add(document);
```

which eventually make an ID and add the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a document to another document.  You can only add a document to a named collection or subcollection.  You will have to somehow provide the name of that collection - the SDK will not generate one for you.

Comment: how to make the subcollection?

Comment: You don't have to "make" it.  Just start writing documents to it, and it will become visible in the console.  Collections are just a way to organize documents for the purpose of indexing.  They are not entities that contain their own data separate from documents.  They are not like folders in desktop OS filesystems that actually exist on disk.